# MCR instance not available

Tags: matlab

I have been using MCR for an application on Windows from version XP to 8.1. But for the same installation of my application and the MCR library under Windows 10, I get "MCR instance not available" error. What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you install the same version of MCR? For a 32bit executable you need to install the 32bit MCR in the matching version.

Comment: Certainly. The application using this dll is 32 bit application. But the computer the app is installed is 64 bit.  So the "MATLAB Component Runtime" (MCR) is installed in the "\Program Files x(86)" folder.  The MCR created in a 32 bit machine and I believe, it used 32 bit version of files from the Matlab library. But the same setup works in Win XP to Win 8.1. I only had this problem in Win 10. So it must be something to the with this OS.

Comment: Check the environment variable `PATH`, does it contain the MCR?

Comment: Hello Daniel. It's too late. After trying a lot of things and talking to Matlab support (who told me that even 2012 version of Matlab is not tested under Win 10), I installed Win 7 on this computer to get my application to work. Thank you for all your support.

Comment: Then I recommend to delete this question.